# Sequelize.js query to get total count through relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize to get a total count through a relationship. I need it by a `customerId` that is in a parent table joined through a pivot table. The plain query looks something like this:

```
SELECT count(p.*) FROM parcels as p
LEFT JOIN orders_parcels as op ON op."parcelId" = p.id
LEFT JOIN orders as o ON op."orderId" = o.id
WHERE o."customerId"=1
```

This works fine. But not sure how to get the sequelize query.

```
Parcel.findAndCountAll();
```

**EDIT: OrderParcel**

```
var OrderParcel = service.sequelize.define('OrderParcel', {

    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'orders_parcels',
    freezeTableName: true,
    paranoid: true
});

module.exports = OrderParcel;

var Order = require('./Order');

OrderParcel.belongsTo(Order, {
    as: 'Order',
    foreignKey: 'orderId'
});

var Parcel = require('../parcel/Parcel');

OrderParcel.belongsTo(Parcel, {
    as: 'Parcel',
    foreignKey: 'parcelId'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `sequelize.query`:

> As there are often use cases in which it is just easier to execute raw
>   / already prepared SQL queries, you can utilize the function
>   `sequelize.query`.

```
var query = "SELECT count(p.*) FROM parcels as p" +
" LEFT JOIN orders_parcels as op ON op."parcelId" = p.id" +
" LEFT JOIN orders as o ON op."orderId" = o.id" +
" WHERE o.customerId=1;";

sequelize.query(query, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).success(function(count){
    console.log(count); // It's show the result of query          
    res.end();
}).catch(function(error){            
    res.send('server-error', {error: error});
});
```

[Raw Queries docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the raw query now, but was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Okay, because the joints I do not see another way.

Comment: @Rob see my answer for avoiding raw queries

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've defined the associations, you can use [Model.findAndCountAll](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findandcountfindoptions-promiseobject).  It'd look something like this:

```
Parcel.findAndCountAll({
  include: [{
    model: OrderParcel,
    required: true,
    include: [{
      model: Order,
      where: {
        customerId: idNum
      }
    }]
  }]
}).then(function(result) { 

});
```

Comment: I'm getting an `Error: OrderParcel is not associated to Parcel`, I've added the `OrderParcel` code to the question.

Comment: Make sure to add in the .hasMany associations as well for Parcel and Order.  You might even be able to use belongsToMany in this table structure.  (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations)

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with [Evan Siroky's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33023294/5506278) approach yet the code has to be simplified to work properly:

```
Parcel.findAndCountAll({
include: [{
  model: Order,
  where: {
    customerId: idNum
  },
  duplicating: false // Add this line for retrieving all objects
}]
}).then(function(result) { 
   console.log('Rows: ' + result.rows + ' Count: ' + result.count)
});
```

**Remember to connect your models with belongsToMany method!**